How is this called? Desktop environment in browser
I have a Synology NAS at home, and you can access it via the browser. When you are logged into the NAS's website, you will see the desktop in the browser, just like you would if you were connected with an HDMI cable to a PC. You can do everything, just like a normal desktop environment, just in the browser.
What is this called? Is there a package where I can set up something like that but on a normal Ubuntu installation?


It is just a fake environment. In any case we have terminals and "remote desktop" on a web. Do you mean such things? So to visualize a desktop on the browser? Or do you want to create own customized environment in a browser? -- fake: as you may notice, when you start a task, the system will not respond until if finish it (e.g. finding and loading all apps you have installed)... nothing multitasking as you may expect on real environments.

Oh those are fake? Yeah I meant to visualize the desktop on the browser. So I can just access an URL on the server via browser, input my credentials and access the desktop. So like teamviewer but in the browser.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_desktop (Webtop) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_virtualization#Remote_desktop_virtualization (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Clients the last client, or a very very old discussion: https://serverfault.com/questions/191879/access-vnc-on-ubuntu-through-web-browser

Have you seen Google Slides or similar web apps before? This isn't all that different from those. You click on some things, other things appear or disappear or happen.
